# Flask get request using value

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have the following form:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('search') }}" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="searchbar" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

In

```
@app.route("/search/<string:searchtext>")
def search(searchtext):
    ...
```

how would I use the value of `searchbar` to generate `<string:searchtext>`? Is there anything I could put as `*value*` in `{{ url_for('search', searchtext=*value*) }}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A form using the method `get` sends the parameters values in the URL, such as: `http://example.com/search?searchbar=foo`

In Flask you can access this value using:

```py
from flask import request

@app.route('/search')
def login():
    searchbar = request.args.get('searchbar')
```

If you want to pass the value in the URL path (`/search/<string:searchtext>`), then you have to redirect the user (using Javascript or a `a` link).